# DB2 convert blob containing HEX to ascii

Tags: sql, type-conversion, db2, hex, blob

I've a table with a blob column containing xml data in hex.

Example table:

| Column | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| Saved | timestamp |
| Cust_id | int |
| XML_Date | blob(16777216) |

When I just query it like so:

```
SELECT SAVED, CUST_ID, XML_DATA
FROM FOO_TABLE
WHERE CUST_ID = 1234
```

I get the following:

| Saved | Cust_id | XML_data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-07 | 1234 | x'3C3F786D6C2076657273696F6E3D22312E302220656E636F64696E673D225554462D38223F3E0A3C6E6F7465732076657273696F6E3D2231223E0A093C6C6162656C733E0A09093C6C6162656C2069643D22302220636F6C6F723D22333044424646223E4C6162656C20313C2F6C6162656C3E' |

Now if I take the Hex, minus the starting x' and ending ' and plug it into a [converter](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) I get the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
    <labels>
        <label id="0" color="30DBFF">Label 1</label>
```

The aim is to do this in DB2. I've tried multiple ways to no avail, even enlisted chatGPT.

```
select cast(hex(xml_data) as varchar(1000))as cnv_xml
```

Results in:

```
SQL0171N  The statement was not processed because the data type, length or 

value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine 

"SYSIBM.HEX" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815
```

then

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(
                    CAST(XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(1000) CCSID UNICODE),
                    '0123456789ABCDEF',
                    x'0123456789ABCDEF'
                ) as CNV_XML
```

gives

```
SQL0622N  The clause "CCSID UNICODE" is invalid for this database.  

SQLSTATE=56031
```

Finally, one that runs but just spits back the original HEX

```
SELECT TRANSLATE(
                    CAST(XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(1000) FOR BIT DATA),
                    '0123456789ABCDEF',
                    x'0123456789ABCDEF'
                ) as CNV_XML
```

I'm pretty sure I don't have the rights to create functions or change the explain table unicode settings.

Is there a way to convert these blobs or am I SOOL?
Thanks.

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?

Comment: @Charles think it's linuxx8664 and  DB2 v11.5.6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not stored in hex, its just plain text.
It looks like that because that is how blob data is displayed.
You can convert it to varchar to see it displayed as text. Do not use HEX or Translate, also the ccsid for utf-8 is 1208.

```
SELECT SAVED, CUST_ID, CAST(XML_DATA AS VARCHAR(32764))
       FROM FOO_TABLE
       WHERE CUST_ID = 1234
```

Comment: Just returns the same HEX: x'3C3F786D...'

Comment: you're right! The blob is just plain text. I'd been checking my results by outputting to .txt, changed that to exporting to .csv. Don't even need to cast the column. Thanks for making me realise my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

You must really have BLOB representation of an XML document in a BLOB field. Not just some "binary string resembling xml contents".
That is, if `XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT XML_DATA)` doesn't return correct XML document, you have to do something on XML_DATA contents on your own to make it work as below.
The string representation of an XML document in the example is converted to BLOB to reproduce your XML_DATA column contents. Note, that your "converter output" shows incorrect document - there are no trailing `</labels></notes>` tags. It's parsed then with `XMLPARSE` and converted to CLOB with `XMLSERIALIZE`.
You may use the `XMLTABLE` function to get some elements or attributes of the XML document needed.

```
WITH FOO_TABLE (SAVED, CUST_ID, XML_DATA) AS (
VALUES 
(
  '2023-06-07'::DATE
, 1234
, CAST ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notes version="1">
<labels>
        <label id="0" color="30DBFF">Label 1</label>
</labels>
</notes>'
AS BLOB (1K))
)
)
SELECT 
  T.SAVED
, T.CUST_ID
-- XML as CLOB
, XMLSERIALIZE (XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT XML_DATA) AS CLOB (1K))
    AS CNV_XML
-- XML elements & attributes as relational columns  
, X.LABEL_ELEMENT
, X.LABEL_ID
, X.LABEL_COLOR
, X.NOTES_VERSION
FROM 
  FOO_TABLE T
-- If you want to get XML elements & attributes
, XMLTABLE 
('$D/notes/labels/label' PASSING XMLPARSE (DOCUMENT XML_DATA) AS "D"
  COLUMNS
    LABEL_ELEMENT   VARCHAR (128)   PATH '.'
  , LABEL_ID        INT             PATH '@id'
  , LABEL_COLOR     VARCHAR (128)   PATH '@color'
  , NOTES_VERSION   INT             PATH '../../@version'
) X
```

| SAVED | CUST_ID | CNV_XML | LABEL_ELEMENT | LABEL_ID | LABEL_COLOR | NOTES_VERSION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-07 | 1234 | <notes version="1"><labels><label id="0" color="30DBFF">Label 1</label></labels></notes> | Label 1 | 0 | 30DBFF | 1 |